# La condición siempre entra en el else por más que esté correcto el valor ingresado

Tags: python

Quiero crear una validación de usuario y tengo problemas en los condicionales ya que siempre entra en el condicional `else` por más que esté correcto el nombre.

```py
nombre = input("NOMBRE: ")
nombre_valido = False
letras_nombre = False
numeros_nombre = False

if 4 <= len(nombre) <= 15 and "_" in nombre:
    
    '''
    El nombre debe tener entre 4 y 15 caracteres y formado entre 
    numeros, letras y el guion bajo.
    '''
    if nombre.isalpha():
        letras_nombre = True
            
    if nombre.isnumeric():
        numeros_nombre = True

    if (letras_nombre) and (numeros_nombre):
        nombre_valido = True
        print("Es valido")

    else:
        print("No es")
```

Comment: ¿Cual problema sería ese que tienes?

Comment: Siempre entra en el else

Comment: [str.isalpha](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) da true cuando TODOS los caracteres de la cadena son letras. Lo mismo con [str.isnumeric](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) pero con números. No pueden ser verdaderos los dos. Si lo que buscas es validar que el nombre solo tenga letras y numeros, entonces lo que buscas es [str.isalnum](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum).

Comment: Otro problema, viendo la consigna, te falta tener en cuenta el guión bajo. Python no tiene ningún método de cadena para detectar que sea alfanumerico o guion bajo. Tendrás que recorrer el nombre caracter por caracter y verificar que dicho sea alfanumerico o igual a guion bajo.

Comment: Si el nombre debe contener al menos una letra, un numero y/o guion bajo, de todas formas tendrías que usar un bucle for, ya que Python tampoco ofrece nada para eso.

Comment: Intenté crando una variable booleana para guion y luego dentro del if de longitud nombre usé esto: 
  for i in nombre:
        if i == "_":
            guion_nombre = True

Comment: Vas bien con eso. Ahora aplica eso con letras y numeros (te recomiendo que sea todo dentro de un solo bucle for, pero si te es más facil, hacé tres bucles for separados). Revisa la documentación y tutoriales de internet sobre isalpha e isnumeric de Python, te será util c:

Comment: Genial, pero si uso isalnum() no sería necesario solo verificar si i es == "_" y si i es alnum()?

Comment: Casi! Solo diría que uses "o" en lugar de "y". Piensa que un caracter no puede ser alfanumerico y a la vez un guion bajo. Cuando usas expresiones boleanas, es como si hablaras con una persona, piensalo asi. En realidad depende de la consigna. No estoy seguro de como se debe validar el nombre.

Comment: Genial, me sirvió. Gracias!

Comment: De nada! Un placer ayudar c:

Answer (score 0):

Una solución usando expresiones regulares.

La expresión regular `[\d\w_]{4,15}` que contenga entre 4 y 15 caracteres alfabéticos, dígito o el signo "_".

Agregando un "$" al final del patrón exijo que no haya caracteres extras al final. Usando `re.match`, fuerzo a que el patrón calce desde un principio

```
import re

patron = re.compile(r"[\d\w_]{4,15}$")

nombre_valido = False
while True:
    nombre = input("NOMBRE: ")
    if patron.match(nombre):
        nombre_valido = True
    else:
        print("No es valido")
```

produce:

```
NOMBRE: aaaa
NOMBRE: 1111
NOMBRE: aaaa_111
NOMBRE: aaaa$
No es valido
NOMBRE: aaa
No es valido
NOMBRE: 1234567890123456
No es valido
NOMBRE:
```

Comment: Podrías también usar fullmatch para decirle al modulo re que toda la cadena debe coincidir con la expresión regular.

Comment: Otra cosa, el \d y _ es redundante, ya que \w incluye letras, numeros y guion bajo.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución menos eficiente podría ser recorrer el string caracter a caracter y utilizar banderas y contadores para verificar que cumpla con las condiciones:

```py
nombre = input('Nombre: ')

numeros = letras = guion_bajo = False
cantidad_caracteres = 0

for caracter in nombre:
    cantidad_caracteres += 1

    if caracter.isnumeric():
        numeros = True
    
    if caracter.isalpha():
        letras = True

    if caracter == '_':
        guion_bajo = True

if numeros and letras and guion_bajo and 4 <= cantidad_caracteres <= 15:
    print('Es valido')
else:
    print('No es')
```

Comment: También agregaría que lo mas conveniente seria meter todo el código dentro de una función main() o run() para intentar seguir las buenas practicas.

Answer (score 0):

##### Problemas

El problema está en que `str.isalpha()` lanzará falso si hay caracteres especiales como `_` o números.
mientras que "str.isnumeric()" lanzará falso si hay un caracter que no represente a un número.

Por lo tanto es imposible que ambos sean verdaderos simultáneamente en una misma variable. `if (letras_nombre) and (numeros_nombre):` nunca se cumplirá. Sobre todo por el caracter `_` pero incluso sin este.

Podrías intentar con `"alfredo1_maussa".isalnum()` pero tendrías que deshacerte del guion bajo `_`:

```py
"alfredo23_maussa".replace("_","").isalnum()
```

###### Alternativa: [isidentifier()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isidentifier.asp)

> The isidentifier() method returns True if the string is a valid identifier, otherwise False.

> A string is considered a valid identifier if it only contains alphanumeric letters (a-z) and (0-9), or underscores (_). A valid identifier cannot start with a number, or contain any spaces.

```py
"alfredo23_maussa".isidentifier()
```

Aunque bueno como tal así no es "obligación" que tenga ambos, números y letras.

##### Alternativa estricta

Otra forma es usando esta lógica:

- Para cada caracter se cumple que es número o letra: `all(i.isdigit() or i.isalpha() for i in nombreA)`
- Tiene al menos un número `any(i.isdigit() for i in nombreA)`
- Tiene al menos una letra `any(i.isnumeric() for i in nombreA)`

Quedando como:

```py
if 4 <= len(nombre) <= 15 and "_" in nombre:
    
    '''
    El nombre debe tener entre 4 y 15 caracteres y formado entre 
    numeros, letras y el guion bajo.
    '''
    nombreA=nombre.replace("_","")
    if all(i.isdigit() or i.isalpha() for i in nombreA) and any(i.isdigit() for i in nombreA) and any(i.isnumeric() for i in nombreA):
        print("Es valido")

    else:
        print("No es")
```